# Using FileWriter with try catch, for IOException with several issues

Tags: java, arraylist, ioexception, filewriter

As I said above I have several issues. I am trying to export my array list 'Inventory' to a .txt file.
Here is the code, any help is more than welcome!

```
import java.io.FileWriter.*;
import java.io.*;

    private void ExportGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
FileWriter writer; 
     try {
        writer = new FileWriter("Inventory.txt");
        for(String str: Inventory) {
          writer.write(str);
      }
        writer.close();
     }catch (IOExeption e){
            AlertOut.setText("I'm afraid your file could not be writen at this time.");
    } finally {
        try {
           writer.close();
     } catch (IOException ignore){}
    }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
```

On line 12: Can not find symbol: Class IOException.
On line 18: Reached end of file while parsing.
On line 20: Illegal start of expression.

Here is the full code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileWriter.*;
import java.io.*;


/**
 *
 * @author matthewmurchison
 */
public class mVentory extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form mVentory
     */
       public mVentory() {
        initComponents();

     }

        public class ProductInfo{
                    String name; 
                    String des; 
                    String ID; 
                    String num; 


    public ProductInfo(String name, String des, String ID, String num){
      this.name = name;
      this.des =des;
      this.ID = ID;
      this.num = num;
    }
}


        /**
     *
     */
   public static void Inventory(){

        }


    //creat Array
        ArrayList <String> Inventory = new ArrayList <String> ();

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        NameIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        IDIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        DesIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        NumIn = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        AddGo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        ExportGo = new javax.swing.JButton();
        AlertOut = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jLabel2.setText("Name:");

        jLabel3.setText("ID");

        jLabel4.setText("Descripion");

        jLabel5.setText("Number");

        NameIn.setText("jTextField1");

        IDIn.setText("jTextField2");
        IDIn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                IDInActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        DesIn.setText("jTextField3");

        NumIn.setText("jTextField4");

        jLabel14.setText("Add");

        jLabel15.setText("Export to .txt");

        AddGo.setText("Add");
        AddGo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                AddGoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        ExportGo.setText("Export");
        ExportGo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ExportGoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        AlertOut.setToolTipText("");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(jLabel14)
                        .add(245, 245, 245))
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                            .add(jLabel15)
                            .add(AddGo)
                            .add(ExportGo))
                        .add(233, 233, 233))))
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .add(225, 225, 225)
                            .add(jLabel1)
                            .add(117, 117, 117))
                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                .add(jLabel2)
                                .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                        .add(jLabel4)
                                        .add(jLabel5)
                                        .add(jLabel3))
                                    .add(18, 18, 18)
                                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING, false)
                                        .add(DesIn)
                                        .add(NumIn)
                                        .add(NameIn)
                                        .add(IDIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 202, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(150, 150, 150)
                        .add(AlertOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 225, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(149, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 22, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(jLabel14)
                .add(18, 18, 18)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                    .add(jLabel2)
                    .add(NameIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                    .add(jLabel3)
                    .add(IDIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                    .add(jLabel4)
                    .add(DesIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                    .add(NumIn, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(jLabel5))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(AddGo)
                .add(18, 18, 18)
                .add(jLabel15)
                .add(40, 40, 40)
                .add(ExportGo)
                .add(18, 18, 18)
                .add(AlertOut, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .add(194, 194, 194))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void IDInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void AddGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // Add Item
        String Name, Description, Identification, Number, Item;


        Name = NameIn.getText();
        Description = DesIn.getText();
        Identification = IDIn.getText();
        Number = NumIn.getText();

        Item = "" + Name + "," + Description + "," + Identification +"," + Number + ".";

        Inventory.add(new String(Item));

        NameIn.setText("");
        DesIn.setText("");
        IDIn.setText("");
        NumIn.setText("");


    }                                     

    private void ExportGoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
FileWriter writer; 
     try {
        writer = new FileWriter("Inventory.txt");
        for(String str: Inventory) {
          writer.write(str);
      }
        writer.close();
     }catch (IOException e){
            AlertOut.setText("I'm afraid your file could not be writen at this time.");
    } finally {
        try {
           writer.close();
     } catch (IOException ignore){}
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mVentory.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mVentory.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mVentory.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mVentory.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new mVentory().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton AddGo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel AlertOut;
    private javax.swing.JTextField DesIn;
    private javax.swing.JButton ExportGo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField IDIn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField NameIn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField NumIn;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Those are the contents of your `.java` file?

Comment: Those are the relevant parts.

Comment: `Reached end of file while parsing.` means there are more relevant parts. You have syntax errors and we cannot know what those are until you've shown us your code. Are the methods you've shown within a class body?

Comment: OK, I just addd the code.

Comment: Match your `{` and `}`.

Comment: Thanks! no more problems, Is that the general solution to that error?

Comment: Your errors were syntax errors. An IDE would be very helpful in pointing those out. Proper formatting also helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can solve is that you misspelled `IOException` in line 12.

Comment: Thats embarsing... thanks! that took care of Class IOExeption part.

Comment: And you are still misspelling it!